# Comparing the rate of convergence of steepest descent method

Tags: optimization, numerical-optimization, gradient-descent, rate-of-convergence

I am wondering if we can compare the convergence rate of optimization methods, measured using different error definition.

For example, from the book *[Optimization for Data Analytics](https://www.cambridge.org/core/books/optimization-for-data-analysis/C02C3708905D236AA354D1CE1739A6A2)*, the authors derived the convergence rate of steepest descent method with constant stepsize $1/L$ on three different cases: 1. general L-smooth, 2. convex + L-smooth, 3. strongly convex with modulus $m$ + L-smooth.

> We have, from (3.7), that an iteration $k$ will be found such that $\lVert \nabla f(x^{k}) \rVert \leq \epsilon$ for some $k \leq T$, where
> $$T \geq \frac{2L(f(x^0) - f^*)}{\epsilon^2}.$$
> For the general convex case, we have from (3.8) that $f(x^k)-f^*\leq \epsilon$ when
> $$k \geq \frac{L\lVert x^0 - x^* \rVert^2}{2 \epsilon}$$
> For the strongly convex case, we have from (3.15) that $f(x^k) - f^* \leq \epsilon$ for all k satisfying
> $$k \geq \frac{L}{M}\log((f(x^0)-f^*)/\epsilon)$$

The book said that the first two cases are sublinear, and the last case is linear. But the first case measured convergence error using the norm of the gradient($\lVert \nabla f(x^{k}) \rVert$), while the latter two cases measured error using the difference between the function value at time $k$ and the optimal function value($f(x^k) - f^*$). Can we still say that the steepest descent method converges **faster** on strongly convex function than on general L-smooth function in this case? Or am I missing something?